# WHMCS IDN and punncycode

Tags: dns, whmcs, idn

I'm having a problem with WHMCS and WHOIS lookups on it. The standard lookup for .de domains is socket://whois.denic.de but whenever i use IDN (example: äch.de) the WHOIS says that the domain is not avaible (remember IDN is enabled) but when i doo a lookup on denic.de äch.de is avaible.

I need to find a workaround (maybe disabling punnycode for .de domains?) or another WHOIS service that would support WHMCS and .de domains.

Help would be appriciated!

With best regards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, i found the problem. Still need a workaround. The problem is that WHMCS is translating the IDN to punnycode right away but denic is using parameters for IDN's and translating the domain himself. Pictures added to main post.

Comment: One more update, managed to get the info from denic and make punnycode work, now the question is how to force WHMCS to use is when üöä is present. Screenshot 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the end there was no asnwer from denic.de or WHMCS or any other prvoder so i made my own filter, connected on my means to my own services from where i query for domains. So, there is a workaround, you need to check how WHMCS is doing queries for domains, relink the whois to your own server with your own script, query the original whois and give the answers to WHMCS from your services.